# How to pass arguments to get_success_url

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Comments
    context_object_name = 'delete_comment'
    template_name = 'blog/comment_delete.html'

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def form_valid(self, comment):
        messages.success(self.request, 'You have deleted the comment')
        return super().form_valid(comment)

    def get_success_url(self):
        post_pk = self.get_object().post.pk
        return reverse('post_detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk': post_pk]))
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} by {self.author}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comments(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(to=Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.author} for {self.post.title}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', home, name='blog_home'),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comments/create/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_create'),
    path('comments/<pk>/', CommentDetailView.as_view(), name='comment_detail'),
    path('comments/<pk>/update/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_update'),
    path('comments/<pk>/delete/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_delete'),

    path('about/', about, name='blog_about'),
]
```

I cant understand how to pass Post primary key to get-*successurl function. Comment model is a foreignkey to Post model.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQFcm.png)

*I have tried to get post pk with get_*object function but it doesnt seem to work. I cant really uderstand how it works and if you can give me some resources where to read or watch about it i would really appreciate it.

Also tried this

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk': self.object.post.pk]))
```

but the same error.

Comment: The default name for primary key for django models is id not pk, what happens if you change `self.get_object().post.pk` to `self.get_object().post.id`

Comment: `['pk': post_pk]` is definitely wrong here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like i said i have a Comment model that is a foreign key to a Post model.  I want CommentDeleteView to redirect me to a post which i delete comment from

Comment: @Daviid `pk` is implicitly added by Django and is kind of a proxy to the actual primary key of the model (Whatever its name may be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should properly pass kwargs

```
class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
  ...

  def get_success_url(self):
      post_pk = self.get_object().post.pk
      return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': post_pk})
```